# MUI v4 PropFunc doesn't work if i provide callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have material ui (MUI) v4 (4.12.4) and faced with a problem of custom styling by PropFunc

if I provide a PropFunc in a common way as callback to get CSS, it works fine

like that:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
   return {
      input: {
        '&:disabled': ({ locked }: InputStyleProps) => ({color: 'red'}),
      }
   },
})
```

if I try to customize my return value by PropFunc which looks like below, I don't see any styles applied on my disabled input

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  const getDisabledCommonStyles = (
    locked: InputStyleProps['locked'],
  ): CSSProperties => ({
    backgroundColor: !locked ? 'transparent' : getLockedBackgroundColor(theme),
    '&::placeholder': {
      color: getDisabledPlaceholderColor(theme, locked),
    },
  });
  const getDisabledStyles = (locked: InputStyleProps['locked']) => {
    const commonStyles = getDisabledCommonStyles(locked);
    return locked && theme.palette.type === ThemeType.DARK
      ? {
          ...commonStyles,
          borderColor: getDisabledLockedBorderColor(theme),
        }
      : commonStyles;
  };
  return {
    input: {
      '&:disabled': ({ locked }: InputStyleProps) => getDisabledStyles(locked),
    },
  };
});
```

Tbh I expected to get a callback which returns CSS object depending on props and works fine. U can be absolutely sure that color getters return a color in css-way without any errors, u can replace them by using `{color: 'red'}` or smth

Also I've tried to use smth like that:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => (inputStyleProps: InputStyleProps) => {
  const { locked } = inputStyleProps;
  
  const getDisabledCommonStyles = (): CSSProperties => ({
    backgroundColor: !locked ? 'transparent' : getLockedBackgroundColor(theme),
    '&::placeholder': {
      color: getDisabledPlaceholderColor(theme, locked),
    },
  });
  
  const getDisabledStyles = () => {
    const commonStyles = getDisabledCommonStyles();
    return locked && theme.palette.type === ThemeType.DARK
      ? {
          ...commonStyles,
          borderColor: getDisabledLockedBorderColor(theme),
        }
      : commonStyles;
  };
  
  return {
    input: {
      '&:disabled': {
        ...getDisabledStyles(),
      },
    },
  };
});
```

Still haven't seen any styles applied on my disabled input

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve that problem, but I found another way:

I simply placed the theme and static styles into the useStyles hook. The callbacks within the hook accept the theme as a parameter, and there is a color getter that looks like `isThemeDark ? DarkColor : LightColor`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  input: {
    '&:disabled': {
      backgroundColor: ({ locked }: InputStyleProps) =>
        !locked ? 'transparent' : getLockedBackgroundColor(theme),
    },
  },
}));
```

For the other variable-dependent styles, I replaced them in the SCSS file and used them like this:

```
const PureField: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const { isError, locked, hoveredLabel, ...inputBaseProps } =
    props;
  const theme = useTheme<UIKitTheme>();
  const isDarkMode = theme.palette.type === ThemeType.DARK;
  const classes = useStyles({ isError, locked });
  return (
    <InputBase
      {...inputBaseProps}
      disabled={inputBaseProps.disabled || locked}
      classes={{
        input: classnames(classes.input, {
          [stylesScss.locked]: locked,
          [stylesScss.dark]: isDarkMode,
          [stylesScss.error]: isError,
        }),
      }}
    />
  );
};
```